# Leading poskim in the Charedi community today

Tags: posek-psak-decisor-ruling

Who are the leading poskim in the Israeli Ashkenazi Charedi community today? As far as I am aware R. Nissim Karelitz is no longer active, so I would like to know who has taken his place and that of Rav Elyashiv zt"l and R. Shmuel Wosner zt"l.

I am not asking who commenters believe should be considered the greatest poskim - I would like to know who regularly answers the most serious and complex shailos, such as yuchsin/mamzeirus and new medical questions and technological issues affecting hilchos shabbos - using verifiable evidence, such as printed teshuvos to shailos referred to them by other rabbonim, or their halachic opinions cited as primary views in mainstream Israeli Charedi publications.

Comment: Rav Wosner was more so for the chassidim. Are you also including chassidish or just litvish?

Comment: And yes, I am including chassidim too.

Comment: @DoubleAA I vote to unhold. The nature of the chareidi world is that its leaders and poskim are easily identifiable. Thus making this a very answerable question.

Comment: @Mefaresh I accept that _you_ think _you_ know clearly who they are. How can you back it up?

Comment: links, articles, annecdotes

Comment: That say what? You mean like a news article that calls Rabbi X a "leading poseik in the ashkenazi charedi community"? The very term I just quoted isn't rigorously defined.

Comment: Has such a title ever been rigorously defined? Was rav Moshe Feinstein ever rigorously vetted?

Comment: @Joseph, I would encourage you to put the criteria that you stated in the comments to the answer into the question itself. It would help it gain reopen votes.

Comment: "Most serious and complex" is still a matter of opinion, IMO. ;)

Comment: This is a ridiculous question, happy it closed.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Chaim Kanievsky

Rav Moshe Sternbuch

Rav Mendel Shafran

Rav Yitzchok Zilberstein

Rav Dovid Grossman

Rav Ezriel Auerbach

Rav Dovid Morgenstern

Rav Sariel Rosenberg

Rav Chaim Zev Malinowitz

Rav Zalman Nechemia Goldberg

Comment: Thank you. A few follow up questions, if I may. I have seen R. Chaim Kanievsky’s opinion quoted on day-to-day issues, but I was not aware that he is consulted for e.g. complex Even Ha’ezer shailos that requite detailed teshuvos.

From what I have heard, R. Shmuel Wosner’s most prominent talmidim are R. Shmuel Eliezer Shtern and R. Moshe Shoul Klein. Where do they fit in with those you listed?

Comment: Also, I recently saw a sefer with haskamos from R. Sariel Rosenberg (Av Beis Din of R. Nisim Karelitz’s beis din and R. Nisim Karelitz’s former son in law) and R. Tzvi Weber (Rav of the Charedi community in Neveh Yaakov). Are they considered leading halachic authorities?

Finally, R. Osher Weiss is very popular in “chutznik” Charedi circles. But do Israeli Charedim consider him a prominent posek?

Comment: Yes the rabbonim you listed are absolutely accepted. My list was is no way comprehensive or meant to exclude anyone. And yes Rav Chaim is asked to rule on complex issues. Though he is definitely not in the mold of traditional poskim. Ala Rav Shlomo zalman, the minchas Yitzchok or the tzitz eliezer. Rav osher Weiss is well accepted.

Comment: Does R. Chaim answer complex questions (e.g. agunos or mamzeirus) in the same concise manner as he does other issues? Or does he write teshuvos as other poskim do?

Comment: And is there any sort of hierarchy as there was in the past (when Rav Wosner, Rav Elyashiv and maybe one or two others were considered "the" poskei hador? Who out of these rabbonim would be most likely to gain broad acceptance for their psak on a mamzeirus question if he disagreed with the others?